# Landing page timeout for LookupOrderedRows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I have a landing page that updates set of records from a Data Extension.

I'm using `LookupOrderedRows()`, but my page timeouts after cetain time.
I tried `LookupRows()` and its working but it is updating only 2000 records. My records are in 100,000. So I'm limiting the rows by specifying Number of rows to return to 20,000. But its not working

```
%%[

   Var @rows, @rowCTSubscribers, @oldband, @newband
   set @oldband = "x"
   set @newband = "y"
   set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("My data extension",20000,"modified ASC","band",@oldband)
   set @rowCTSubscribers = rowCount(@rows)

  For @i = 1 to @rowCTSubscribers do
  Set @rowSubscribers = row(@rows,@i)

   set @emailaddress = field(@rowSubscribers, 'emailaddress')

   UpdateData("ent.transfer","1","emailaddress",@emailaddress,"band",@newband)

next @i

]%%
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Rows effected - %%=v(@rowCTSubscribers)=%%
Update complete
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SSJS API call to Retrieve DataExtensionObject (Data Extension Rows) meeting your criteria and wrap it with do/while statement. This will allow you to retrieve more than 2000 records. Example:

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core", "1.2");

var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "DataExtensionObject[put-lookup-data-extension-key-here]"); 
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Field1");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Field2");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Field3"); //You can add more fields 

var filter = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter, "Property", "LookupFieldName"); 
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(filter, "SimpleOperator", "equals"); 
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(filter, "Value", "LookupFieldValue");

Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", filter); 

do {
    var results = [0,0];
    var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);
    var status = results[0];
    var requestId = results[1];
    if (rows != null) {
        //Do something here
    }
    rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;
}
while (status == "MoreDataAvailable") //Continue retrieving more data
</script>
```